Warning when updating the distribution
I manage some servers that are running Ubuntu Server 22.04.5 LTS (jammy) distribution.
On some servers I managed to upgrade to version 24.04.1 LTS (noble) using the "do-release-upgrade" command. On other servers I get this warning:
# do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Could not find the release announcement
The server may be overloaded.

I've been trying for a few days now, but without success.
So I don't know if it's something related to the hardware of these old machines, or if the Ubuntu servers are actually overloaded.
Does anyone know the reason for this message?
Thanks.

The machines where I had the same problem could not retrieve http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/ReleaseAnnouncement. They are behind an APT Proxy server (squid-deb-proxy) which has HTTP traffic blocked by the corporate firewall (only HTTPS and APT-GET traffic were allowed).
Maybe it's the same for you?
